# java.lang.Exception: Error while transmitting data how to solve this error

Tags: java, exception, client

I am trying to send a file from server side to client side upon request. The file that is sent is encrypted and the client shpuld decrypt it. the encryption process works fine but while decrypting i need to have the DerIOBuffer objetc which I have using serializing. what should i do..please help

server:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

import java.math.BigInteger;
import com.dragongate_technologies.borZoi.*;

public class FileServer {

  static final int LISTENING_PORT = 3210;


  public static void main(String[] args) {

     File directory;        // The directory from which the gets the files that it serves.
     ServerSocket listener; // Listens for connection requests.
     Socket connection;     // A socket for communicating with a client.


     /* Check that there is a command-line argument.
        If not, print a usage message and end. */

     if (args.length == 0) {
        System.out.println("Usage:  java FileServer <directory>");
        return;
     }

     /* Get the directory name from the command line, and make
        it into a file object.  Check that the file exists and
        is in fact a directory. */

     directory = new File(args[0]);
     if ( ! directory.exists() ) {
        System.out.println("Specified directory does not exist.");
        return;
     }
     if (! directory.isDirectory() ) {
        System.out.println("The specified file is not a directory.");
        return;
     }

     /* Listen for connection requests from clients.  For
        each connection, create a separate Thread of type
        ConnectionHandler to process it.  The ConnectionHandler
        class is defined below.  The server runs until the
        program is terminated, for example by a CONTROL-C. */

     try {
        listener = new ServerSocket(LISTENING_PORT);
        System.out.println("Listening on port " + LISTENING_PORT);
        while (true) {
           connection = listener.accept();
           new ConnectionHandler(directory,connection);
        }
     }
     catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Server shut down unexpectedly.");
        System.out.println("Error:  " + e);
        return;
     }

  } // end main()



  static class ConnectionHandler extends Thread {
       // An object of this class is a thread that will
       // process the connection with one client.  The
       // thread starts itself in the constructor.

     File directory;       // The directory from which files are served
     Socket connection;    // A connection to the client.
     TextReader incoming;  // For reading data from the client.
     PrintWriter outgoing; // For transmitting data to the client.


     ConnectionHandler(File dir, Socket conn) {
           // Constructor.  Record the connection and
           // the directory and start the thread running.
        directory = dir;
        connection = conn;
        start();
     }


     void sendIndex() throws Exception {
           // This is called by the run() method in response
           // to an "index" command.  Send the list of files
           // in the directory.
        String[] fileList = directory.list();
        for (int i = 0; i < fileList.length; i++)
           outgoing.println(fileList[i]);
        outgoing.flush();
        outgoing.close();
        if (outgoing.checkError())
           throw new Exception("Error while transmitting data.");
     }


     void ecies_ex(String fileName) throws Exception {
           // This function encrypts the file that has been requested
           // by the client.

        String at1,dc1,der1;

        OutputStream os = connection.getOutputStream();
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(os);

        ECDomainParameters dp = ECDomainParameters.NIST_B_163();

        ECPrivKey skA = new ECPrivKey(dp, BigInteger.valueOf(123));
        ECPubKey pkA = new ECPubKey(skA);

        ECPrivKey skB = new ECPrivKey(dp, BigInteger.valueOf(230));
        ECPubKey pkB = new ECPubKey(skB);

        File file = new File(directory,fileName);
        if ( (! file.exists()) || file.isDirectory()) {
             // (Note:  Don't try to send a directory, which
             // shouldn't be there anyway.)
           outgoing.println("error");
        }
        else {
           outgoing.println("ok");

           String pt1 = new String();
           BufferedReader br = null;

        try {
           String sCurrentLine;

           br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
           while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                pt1=pt1+"\n"+sCurrentLine;
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        ECIES crypt = new ECIES(skA, pkB, pt1.getBytes()); // encrypt the data

        try {
            DerIOBuffer der = new DerIOBuffer(crypt);

            oos.writeObject(der);
            ECIES decrypt = der.toECIES();
            dc1=decrypt.toString2(); //cipher text

            //at1=decrypt.toString3(); //authentication tag

            FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter("encrypted.txt");
            BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);
            out.write(dc1);
            //Close the output stream
            out.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.toString());
        }

        TextReader fileIn = new TextReader( new FileReader("encrypted.txt") );
        while (fileIn.peek() != '\0') {
            // Read and send lines from the file until
            // an end-of-file is encountered.
            String line = fileIn.getln();
            outgoing.println(line);
        }
      }
      outgoing.flush();
    //  oos.close();
    //  os.close();
      outgoing.close();
      if (outgoing.checkError())
        throw new Exception("Error while transmitting data.");

}




     public void run() {
           // This is the method that is executed by the thread.
           // It creates streams for communicating with the client,
           // reads a command from the client, and carries out that
           // command.  The connection is logged to standard output.
           // An output beginning with ERROR indicates that a network
           // error occurred.  A line beginning with OK means that
           // there was no network error, but does not imply that the
           // command from the client was a legal command.
        String command = "Command not read";
        try {
           incoming = new TextReader( connection.getInputStream() );
           outgoing = new PrintWriter( connection.getOutputStream() );
           command = incoming.getln();
           if (command.equals("index")) {
              sendIndex();
           }
           else if (command.startsWith("get")){
              String fileName = command.substring(3).trim();
              ecies_ex(fileName);
              //sendFile(fileName);
           }
           else {
              outgoing.println("unknown command");
              outgoing.flush();
           }
           System.out.println("OK    " + connection.getInetAddress()
                                       + " " + command);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
           System.out.println("ERROR " + connection.getInetAddress()
                                    + " " + command + " " + e);
        }
        finally {
           try {
              connection.close();
           }
           catch (IOException e) {
           }
        }
     }

  }  // end nested class ConnectionHandler


} //end class FileServer
```

client :

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import com.dragongate_technologies.borZoi.*;


public class FileClient {

  static final int LISTENING_PORT = 3210;


  public static void main(String[] args) {

     String computer;      // Name or IP address of server.
     Socket connection;    // A socket for communicating with that computer.
     PrintWriter outgoing; // Stream for sending a command to the server.
     TextReader incoming;  // Stream for reading data from the connection.
     String command;       // Command to send to the server.
     String pt3;


    ECDomainParameters dp = ECDomainParameters.NIST_B_163();
     ECPrivKey skB = new ECPrivKey(dp, BigInteger.valueOf(230));
    //ECPrivKey skB = new ECPrivKey (dp);
    ECPubKey pkB = new ECPubKey(skB);
     /* Check that the number of command-line arguments is legal.
        If not, print a usage message and end. */



     if (args.length == 0 || args.length > 3) {
        System.out.println("Usage:  java FileClient <server>");
        System.out.println("    or  java FileClient <server> <file>");
        System.out.println("    or  java FileClient <server> <file> <local-file>");
        return;
     }

     /* Get the server name and the message to send to the server. */

     computer = args[0];

     if (args.length == 1)
        command = "index";
     else
        command = "get " + args[1];

     /* Make the connection and open streams for communication.
        Send the command to the server.  If something fails
        during this process, print an error message and end. */

     try {
        connection = new Socket( computer, LISTENING_PORT );
        incoming = new TextReader( connection.getInputStream() );
        outgoing = new PrintWriter( connection.getOutputStream() );


        outgoing.println(command);
        outgoing.flush();
     }
     catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(
             "Can't make connection to server at \"" + args[0] + "\".");
        System.out.println("Error:  " + e);
        return;
     }

     /* Read and process the server's response to the command. */

     try {
        if (args.length == 1) {
              // The command was "index".  Read and display lines
              // from the server until the end-of-stream is reached.
           System.out.println("File list from server:");
           while (incoming.eof() == false) {
              String line = incoming.getln();
              System.out.println("   " + line);
           }
        }
        else {
              // The command was "get <file-name>".  Read the server's
              // response message.  If the message is "ok", get the file.
           String message = incoming.getln();
           if (! message.equals("ok")) {
              System.out.println("File not found on server.");
              return;
           }
           PrintWriter fileOut;  // For writing the received data to a file.
           if (args.length == 3) {
                 // Use the third parameter as a file name.
               fileOut = new PrintWriter( new FileWriter(args[2]) );
           }
           else {
                 // Use the second parameter as a file name,
                 // but don't replace an existing file.
               File file = new File(args[1]);
               if (file.exists()) {
                  System.out.println("A file with that name already exists.");
                  System.out.println("To replace it, use the three-argument");
                  System.out.println("version of the command.");
                  return;
               }
               fileOut = new PrintWriter( new FileWriter(args[1]) );
           }
           while (incoming.peek() != '\0') {
                  // Copy lines from incoming to the file until
                  // the end of the incoming stream is encountered.
               String line = incoming.getln();
               fileOut.println(line);
           }
           InputStream is = connection.getInputStream(); 
           ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(is); 
           DerIOBuffer der = (DerIOBuffer)ois.readObject();
           ECIES decrypt = der.toECIES();

           byte[] pt2 = decrypt.decrypt(skB); // decrypt the data
            pt3=new String(pt2);

           if (fileOut.checkError()) {
              System.out.println("Some error occurred while writing the file.");
              System.out.println("Output file might be empty or incomplete.");
           }
        }
     }
     catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Sorry, an error occurred while reading data from the server.");
        System.out.println("Error: " + e);
     }

  }  // end main()


 } //end class FileClient
```

Comment: The `DerIOBuffer` should be `Serializable` and the class file of `DerIOBuffer ` must exist on client side also. Else it wont work.

Answer (score 1):

If you care about errors, you should not use `PrintWriter`.  Why?  Because if an error does occur on output via a `PrintWriter`, you have no way to find out what it was.  This is what makes it difficult to figure out what the real problem is in this case.  I recommend that you fix this so that you can get to the real cause of the problem.

The real problem *could* be related to to the following issues:

- If the stuff you are trying to write *could* be binary, you shouldn't use `PrintWriter` ... or Readers / Writers at all.
- You seem to be using Object serialization unnecessarily ... and on a class that looks like it may not be serializable.
- Based on the difficulty I had in finding documentation for the "borZoi" library ... and other things ... I think you may have made a poor choice of library for doing crypto work.